# traffic coming from pinterest not showing in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, pinterest

Pinterest's analytics showing I got some click from my pin. Traffic comes from Pinterest on my website, but Google Analytics not showing traffic coming from Pinterest. What could be the reason?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that the referrer is not passed from Pinterest to your site, when the user clicks on the link. You can easily fix this by adding UTM parameters to your link.

In this post you can read [how to use UTM parameters](https://analyticshelp.io/blog/what-why-how-use-utm-parameters-track-campaigns-performance/)